# How to export metadata from Cloudera

Tags: hadoop, hive, metadata, apache-pig, hdfs

I'm just beginning with Hadoop based systems and I am working in Cloudera 5.2 at the moment.  I am trying to get metadata out of HDFS/Hive and into some other software.  When I say metadata I mean stuff like:
- for Hive: database schema and table schema
- for HDFS: the directory structure in HDFS, creation and modification times, owner and access controls

Does anyone know how to export the table schema's from Hive into a table or CSV file?

It seems that the Hive EXPORT function doesn't support only providing the schema.  I found the Pig DESCRIBE function but I'm not sure how to get the output into a table-like structure; seems to only be available on the screen.

Thanks

Comment: For alternatives, software recommendations: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ This question probably not too well fit for this site.

Comment: Thanks Gabor.  I modified the question so it is more specific.  Hopefully this works better for this site.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, cloudera uses a postgres database to store different configurations... you may be able to interact with that to get what you want.

Comment: you can make your hive metadata in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudera Navigator can be used to manage/export metadata from HDFS and Hive. The Navigator Metadata Server periodically collects the cluster's metadata information and provides a REST API for retrieving metadata information. More details at http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-navigator/v2-latest/Cloudera-Navigator-Installation-and-User-Guide/cnui_metadata_arch.html.

I'm not familiar with Hive, but you can also extract HDFS metadata by:

1. Fetching the HDFS fsimage. "hdfs dfsadmin -fetchImage ./fsimage"
2. Processing the fsimage using the OfflineImageViewer. "hdfs oiv XML -i ./fsimage -o ./fsimage.out"

More information about the HDFS OIV at https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsImageViewer.html.